# GGTS repetitive method name/signature error in controllers

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy, spring-tool-suite

I am using latest GGTS v3.4 based on eclipse 4.3.1 64bit version for development app on Grails 2.3.2. Every single controller that is in my classpath has an error in it. There are two identical errors per every controller class.

> Groovy:Repetitive method name/signature for method 'java.lang.Object withFormat(groovy.lang.Closure)' in class 'package.SomeController'.
>
> SomeController.groovy /appname/grails-app/controllers/package line 1
>
> Java Problem

Everything just work, but my `Problems` tab is getting quite messy.

Comment: `package` is a reserved word, you cannot use it as package name.

Comment: I didn't. By 'package' I mean 'org.company.example'.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a problem when you run GGTS with JDK8. Switching to JDK7 fixes the problem until the problem is fixed.

See issue comments of [STS-3696](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3696?focusedCommentId=100168&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-100168)

Comment: I had the same issue, downgrading to jdk7 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I usually have this issue in GGTS whenever I start a project. Look at your Project properties and check to make sure the correct version of Groovy is selected for the workspace.

I'll find the Groovy version is set to 1.8 when I'm using 2.0.

Comment: Unfortunately switching (synchronously - workspace + project) among different groovy versions didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to **Grails 2.4.4** fixed the issue for me.

My conf of GGTS is:
Version: **3.6.3.RELEASE**
Platform: **Eclipse Kepler SR2 (4.3.2)**

**JDK 1.7**

Answer (score 0):

It could be one of several reasons.

1. Grails Version in **Window -> Preference -> Groovy -> Grails**.
2. Groovy Version in **Window -> Preference -> Groovy -> Compiler**.
3. Java Version is not set correctly. It's your **PATH** instead of under **Window -> Preference -> Java -> Installed JREs**. If it doesn't match the Groovy/Grails for your workspace/project, there would be error.

For example, I run into this problem when I am using Grails 2.3.1, Groovy 2.1.8. My Java version is 1.8, which is incompatible with Groovy 2.1.8. I changed it to 1.7, restarted GGTS, the problems are gone.