# Repetitive method name/signature for method compilation error when using @I18nFields

Tags: grails, internationalization, grails-2.3

I get repetitive method name/Signature compilation failure when i try to use `i18nFields` in my domain class to support multiple languages.

**Grails Version** : 2.3.7 ( I tried with 2.3.4 and got the same issue and upgraded)

Documentation from Grails followed for this was http://grails.org/plugin/i18n-fields

My Domain class looks like

```
package com.sampleapp.domain

import i18nfields.I18nFields;

@I18nFields
class Products {

 def name

 static constraints = {}

 static i18nFields = ['name']
}
```

My `Config.groovy` has the below line included to specify the locale

```
// internationalization support - testing 
i18nFields {
    locales = ['en','es']
}
```

BuildConfig.groovy plugin definition

```
plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.47"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.0.1"
    compile ':cache:1.1.1'

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime  ":hibernate:3.6.10.6" // or":hibernate4:4.1.11"//
    runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
    runtime ":jquery:1.10.2.2"
//  compile  ":jquery-ui:1.10.2.2"
    runtime ":resources:1.2.1"
    // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
    runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0.1"
    runtime ":cached-resources:1.1"
    //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

    compile ':platform-core:1.0.RC6'
    compile ":cache-headers:1.1.5"
    runtime ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC2'
    // internationalization
    compile ":i18n-fields:0.8.1"
}
```

The compilation error is

```
grails-workspace\Test\grails-app\domain\com\sampleapp\domain\Products.groovy: -1: Repetitive method name/signature for method 'void setName_es(java.lang.String)' in class 'com.sampleapp.domain.Products'.
 @ line -1, column -1.
```

The Error is repeated for the name property for both en and es locales twice.

There is no error if i remove the i18nFields annotation and the sample app worked fine before this. I verified [GGTS repetitive method name/signature error in controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111985/ggts-repetitive-method-name-signature-error-in-controllers) post for similar error in controller. I have also verified to ensure that groovy version is correct and in my case it is 2.1

Can somebody please give me any pointers on where i should look to resolve this issue.

Comment: I got the same problem in grails 2.3.4 with jdk 1.8, reverting back solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it has something to do with the new Binding mechanism in grails 2.3. Maybe the  getters and setters are set automatic now?

When I comment out these two lines in ClassI18nalizator.groovy the error disappears. It seems to work at least partly. I can use the fields in scaffolding. It's not a real solution but maybe a hint for someone who understands grails better than me.

```
    private def getSetterMethod(field) {
            // setter should return void. that's why the return statement.
            //return new AstBuilder().buildFromString("i18nfields.I18nFieldsHelper.setValue(this, '${field}', value); return;").pop();
    }

    private def getGetterMethod(field) {
            //new AstBuilder().buildFromString("i18nfields.I18nFieldsHelper.getValueOrDefault(this, '${field[0..-7]}', '${field[-5..-1]}')").pop();
    }
```

After that I run into a second issue:

> No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigObject.contain() is
>   applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [en_US]

I solved it by adding redisLocale to Config.groovy

```
i18nFields { 
    locales = ['de_DE', 'en_US']
    defaultLocale = "en_US"
    redisLocales = ['de_DE', 'en_US']
}
```

Comment: Thank You. Your solution worked. for the second issue wrt No signature method : groovy.util.ConfigObject.contain() i got the same while loading the gsp. I passed the language parameter along with the field name to resolve the same.

Comment: I also had to set the defaultLocale in Config.groovy:

i18nFields {
 locales = ['de_DE', 'en_US']
 defaultLocale = "en_US"
}

Answer (score 10):

This problem shows up when you are trying to use Java > v7 with any version of Grails < 2.3.7.  Either downgrade your jvm or upgrade your grails.

Comment: This. Was trying to run grails 2.3.5 on java 8 sdk and this error popped up everywhere. I installed the latest version of java 7 sdk I could find and it worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for trying (and for making me know via github ;) )

The issue was known but hadn't been tackled yet.
The previous answer (commenting out methods) is not exact, event though it follows the right track, because the problem comes from new changes in Grails that will cause a collision in getters and setters.

The solution I've found is to separately create the property and the getter/setter, and it seems to work.

I'm releasing a new version as soon as it can be fully tested in a project, but code is already available in https://github.com/jorgeuriarte/grails-i18n-fields-plugin/tree/redis_integration (version 0.9-redis-SNAPSHOT) in case you want to use it.